# HM-10 pairing with another HM-10 without knowing the MAC addess

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, arduino-uno, arduino-c++, hm-10

I'm trying to figure out, how to connect two hm-10 module, when I do not know the slave MAC address. Imagine you have an electric longboard and lost you remote. You got yourself a new one and now want to pair with the board.

In the data sheet I cannot find any useful functions, to make this process easy.
I thought about making an unique name of the slave device and by making a pairing button on the master device. The pairing button would set the master device in the pairing mode (AT-ROLE1, AT+IMME1 in order to execute AT+DISC?). The results of the AT+DISC? command would be saved to an array and after finding the unique name of slave device, the index of the device/MAC address would be saved and used as a parameter for establishing the connection.
I'm using the firmware version v707.

The problem is, I do not find this solution as elegant and I think there must be a better way to do that, but I cannot find any information about it. Did anyone tried to do that and maybe has some insight? I'd very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Only way I can think of on the HM10 is setting a unique name and scanning for that name.

Another way I have seen is some devices allow you to see service UUIDs in the advertising information so you can connect to the device that has the desired service UUID. But this doesn't seem possible on the HM10